# c segmentation core dump?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I have a function to add vectors and store result, i can not work out why i am getting a segmentation core dump. Havn't done C in a while :/

```
void add(int *a, int *b, int *c, int n){
   int i;

   for(i = 0 ; i < n; n++)
   {
     c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
     i++;
   }

}

int main() {
 // vector_size = 100000
 // vector_a init with 100000 values
 // vector_b init with 100000 values

 int *result = malloc(vector_size * sizeof(int));
 add(vector_a,vector_b,result,vector_size);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are increasing `n` instead of just `i`, the for loop should look like:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

In your code eventually the variable `i` will get larger than `vector_size`, leading to a segmentation fault.

Comment: codify `\`n\`` and `\`i\``

Answer (score 4):

Fix code in such a way (you got an infinite loop):

```
for(i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
{
   c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

Comment: got it, i had target fixation with array and did not notice the loop.. thanks